# Compile Error:variables strElement,StrRow, and strMatrix already defined in method toString(), Whats Wrong?

Tags: java

I keep on getting a compile error thats saying strElement,strRow, and strMatrix are already defined. What am I doing wrong?

```
public String toString() {
    String strMatrix;
    String strRow;
    String strElement;

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            String strElement = String.valueOf(matrix[i][j]);
            String strRow = strRow + strElement + "\t";
        }
        String strMatrix =  strMatrix + strRow + "\n";
    }
    return strMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define those String variables twice.

```
public String toString() {
    String strMatrix; // once
    String strRow; // once
    String strElement; // once

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            String strElement = String.valueOf(matrix[i][j]); // twice
            String strRow = strRow + strElement + "\t"; // twice
        }
        String strMatrix =  strMatrix + strRow + "\n"; // twice
    }
    return strMatrix;
}
```

Fix :

```
public String toString() {
    String strMatrix = null;
    String strRow = null;
    String strElement = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            strElement = String.valueOf(matrix[i][j]);
            strRow = strRow + strElement + "\t";
        }
        strMatrix =  strMatrix + strRow + "\n";
    }
    return strMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare this variables inside the loop because you have already declared them. Just remove `String` before those lines:

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            strElement = String.valueOf(matrix[i][j]);
            strRow = strRow + strElement + "\t";
        }
        strMatrix =  strMatrix + strRow + "\n";
    }
    return strMatrix;
```

Answer (score 0):

You needs to initialize the variable just before use them.

```
String strMatrix;
String strRow;
String strElement;
```

Eg:

```
String strMatrix=null;
String strRow=null;
String strElement=null;
```

Other case is you can't define same variable more than one time in the same scope.

```
String strMatrix; //initialize this
String strRow; // same issue
String strElement; // same issue

for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
       String strElement = String.valueOf(matrix[i][j]); // can't define twice 
       String strRow = strRow + strElement + "\t";// same issue
    }
    String strMatrix =  strMatrix + strRow + "\n";// same issue
}
return strMatrix;
```